# Text Area input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, input, textarea

My view code:

```
%input{:type=>"textarea", :rows=>"3", :value=>"bla bla bla", :name=>"header", :style=>"width: 815px;"}
```

However, it doesn't have 3 rows.

This one seems to be working though:

```
%input{:type=>"text", :value=>"bla bla bla", :name=>"keywords", :style=>"width: 815px;"}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Just found out how to do it. Maybe it helps someone else.

```
    %textarea{:rows=>"3", :name=>"header", :style=>"width: 815px;"}
        bla bla bla
```

The  tag defines a multi-line text input control.(Source: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_textarea.asp)